# How to Create Gradient map from GRID file in QGIS-3 Above?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, heat-map

I have a very important Question. I have a `GRD` file which can be opened in **SURFER** or **QGIS** or **GIS**.

The problem is that how can I customize and make my grid file perfect?

*Here I have two photos which will explain my issue correctly:*

[image: GRD file edited using **SURFER**]
this file is the one I'm expecting to create but it's been made using Surfer program. I want to make it this much perfect with QGIS but it only gives me the result below after putting too much time on it:
[image: GRD file edited using **QGIS**]

if there's a better way to do this please explain it with details. QGIS has so many options and I'm not completely familiar with them.

I have created contours from My raster data, then polygonized and categorized them using Graduated type.

the results are shown below:

[image: Results]

As you can see the map has become full of square pixels. I need to have it just like Surfer **SMOOTHLY** as were shown.

Regards.

Comment: Try creating contours from your raster data, then polygonizing and categorizing them

Comment: @csk I have done it. everything is OK but the map is in pixel form. how can I make the boundaries more smooth?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. If you created contours as I suggested, there wouldn't be "pixels." If you're doing something else, please [edit] your question and explain what you've tried so far. Without knowing that, we can only make random guesses about how to help.

Comment: @csk I have add the result at the end of the question. thank you for your help.

Comment: Rasters are not my area of expertise; I've made all the suggestions I can. There's a whole community on this site, so be patient and hopefully someone with more familiarity with rasters will be able to help you.

Comment: @csk that's great. thank you for your helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to accomplish in QGIS? Maybe this can be done in Surfer? For example, if you're trying to create a gradient map (a map showing slope or gradient values), use the Grid Calculus command in Surfer (Grids | Calculate | Calculus) with the Gradient Operator to create a new grid file of the slopes (rise/run). Then you can create the map in Surfer (either contour or color relief, etc).

Comment: I'm full aware of surfer and I can manage to plot the map perfectly. But I'm just curious that can I plot the gradient map as perfect as surfer?